# How to configure setup.py work with main method?

Tags: setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I made my tool executable and added `__name__:main` method which I want to give to my `setup.py`. This is what it looks like:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name='client',
    version='0.0.1',
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'client = client.main:main'
        ]
    }
)
```

I do not have an __init__.py file, because I want to run my tool as a script, not as a package. I am struggling with the following error -> No module named 'client.main:main. How am I supposed to solve this?

The directory level of my tool is:

```
requests\
   client.py
   setup.py
```

Comment: Could you show the directory structure of your project, this might help us getting a clearer view of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, of course. I updated the post.

Comment: Alright the notation is `executable_name = package.module:function` or `module:function` so I guess in your case you might want: `client = client:main`.